# how to get managedObjectContext to work in multiple views

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am having trouble accessing my coredata objects from multiple views and have read that you have to declare it in your app delegate differently.. But I havent found an example that makes sense to me yet.

This is how I am currently declaring it in my app delegate.

//try setting up context for coredata
    EResponses *eResponses = [EResponses sharedManager];
    eResponses.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

I am wondering how I could get this to work for multiple views? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can reference it from the application delegate (like you are doing).

Or you can setup a singleton class that holds the managed object context. That's how I'm doing it. I'm having a singleton class with all the Core Data functionality adn whenever I need to do some database manipulation I use my Core Data singleton class.

Comment: ah right. I get what your saying.. was hoping to avoid that but its okay.. will just have to get cracking on it :P

Comment: Hey man I have tried your thing but it just isnt working out for me.. When I call the two methods I have in my coredatacontroller class (which is a singletton pattern.. it dosnt even access the class.

Comment: What isn't working for you specifically? Show me some error logs.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong.. I wasnt setting up the sharedManager in the view I was using it from... so managed to fix it with a single line of code **coreDataController = [CoreDataController sharedManager];**